How to Show Only Highlighted Stack Value in Tooltip for Stacked Column Chart in FusionCharts
I am using FusionCharts in JavaScript to create a stacked column chart. When I hover over any stack in the chart, the tooltip displays the highlighted value of the stack along with the non-highlighted values of the other stacks in the same bar. Here is an example of what I am seeing:
Image Link
Documentation : https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes/stackedcolumn2d
I would like to customize the tooltip so that it only shows the value of the highlighted stack and hides the other values. Below is the code I am currently using:
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'stackedcolumn2d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '700',
    height: '400',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "theme": "fusion",
        "caption": "Revenue split by product category",
        "subCaption": "For current year",
        "xAxisname": "Quarter",
        "yAxisName": "Revenues (In USD)",
        //Showing the Cumulative Sum of stacked data
        "showSum": "1",
        "numberPrefix": "$",
        "theme": "fusion"
      },
      "categories": [{
        "category": [{
            "label": "Q1"
          },
          {
            "label": "Q2"
          },
          {
            "label": "Q3"
          },
          {
            "label": "Q4"
          }
        ]
      }],
      "dataset": [{
          "seriesname": "Food Products",
          "data": [{
              "value": "11000"
            },
            {
              "value": "15000"
            },
            {
              "value": "13500"
            },
            {
              "value": "15000"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seriesname": "Non-Food Products",
          "data": [{
              "value": "11400"
            },
            {
              "value": "14800"
            },
            {
              "value": "8300"
            },
            {
              "value": "11800"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }).render();
});

